# Animate Bootstrap Column Break-points

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm just wondering if there is any way to animate a bootstrap column break-point. For example I have this simple column setup:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now as you can see on small devices this will display the div's on separate lines using `col-sm-12`.

I'd like to be able to make a nice transition when this break-point has been reached. At the moment when I scale my browsers view-port down there is no transition. I wouldn't mind the column to fade onto the new line or slide down instead of instantly breaking onto the new line.

I have tried using CSS transition all:

```
-moz-transition: all .5s linear;
-webkit-transition: all .5s linear;
transition: all .5s linear;
```

However this does not work, it simply transitions the width's of the columns and not the break-point onto the new line.

Any idea how this might be possible?

Thanks, Nick

Comment: Why exactly would you want to place a transition there? It is unlikely the people browsing your site are adjusting their browser (which is the only way they'd even notice this transition). They either open it on regular desktop, tablet or mobile, where the possible column break-points have already taken their place.

Comment: What **property** do you expect to transition? Document reflow / wrappiing isn't transitionable as it's not controlled by CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You need to target the div with class="col-md-6 col-sm-12".

Like this:

```
.col-md-6.col-sm-12 {
  transition: all 1.5s linear; 
  -o-transition: all 1.5s linear; 
  -moz-transition: all 1.5s linear; 
  -webkit-transition: all 1.5s linear;
}
```

I've added a bit longer transition so that you can observe the effect better.